# Counting records with some conditions in a table and displaying with a button on a form

Tags: database, ms-access, count

In Access I have this table   tblcls

[image: tblcls]

I have a button on a form. I need some code/vba/SQL etc. for this button so when my client clicks it, they see something like in image2. Where for example.. State OK has 2 English classes, 4 Maths classes, and 3 Science classes. Please note that there won't be more classes, so no more columns  but there will be coming more states and cities so the table there will be growing by rows.

[image]

Comment: What is your question? You didn't ask one. Please see [ask]. Also show what you have tried so far, and where exactly you got stuck or why you didn't manage to solve it on your own. Otherwise this is just asking us to do all the work for you.

Comment: Sorry,  but I can't put there everything that I tried including Crosstab query, DCOUNT, COUNT(*),  web suggestions, codes,

Comment: The relevant infos would be sufficent. But they are missing. Sample data (**NO IMAGES**) as formated text and code sample won't hurt you.

Comment: Your main problem is, that your table is not normalised. Browse for this: _How to normalize a database_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that any of the three class fields can contain any subject, the desired result can be obtained using simple conditional aggregation, e.g.:

```sql
select 
    t.state, 
    -Sum(t.[Class 1]="English" or t.[Class 2]="English" or t.[Class 3]="English"), 
    -Sum(t.[Class 1]="Maths"   or t.[Class 2]="Maths"   or t.[Class 3]="Maths"  ),
    -Sum(t.[Class 1]="Science" or t.[Class 2]="Science" or t.[Class 3]="Science")
from tblcls t
group by t.state
```

However, the clunkiness & inelegance of this solution is due to the fact that your database does not adhere to [database normalisation rules](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics).

For example, since a state may offer many classes, and a class may be taught in many states, you are working with a many-to-many relationship between states & classes, and so a better way to structure the database whilst adhering the [rules of database normalisation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics) would be to make use of a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

Hence, at the very least you may have four tables:

#### States

```
+--------------+
| StateID (PK) |
| StateName    |
+--------------+
```

#### Cities

```
+--------------+
| CityID (PK)  |
| StateID (FK) |
| CityName     |
+--------------+
```

#### Classes

```
+--------------+
| ClassID (PK) |
| ClassName    |
+--------------+
```

#### City_Class_Xref

```
+--------------+
| ID (PK)      |
| CityID (FK)  |
| ClassID (FK) |
| StartDate    |
| EndDate      |
| Cost         |
+--------------+
```

With this structure, there are now many ways to obtain your desired output - one possible method is using a crosstab query, e.g.:

```sql
transform count(*)
select states.statename
from 
    states inner join 
    (
        cities inner join 
        (
            classes inner join city_class_xref on 
            classes.classid = city_class_xref.classid
        )
        on cities.cityid = city_class_xref.cityid
    )
    on states.stateid = cities.stateid
group by states.statename
pivot classes.classname
```

The beauty of this approach is that if you later decide to add or remove a class, city, or state, the query remains unchanged as nothing has been hard-coded - upon adding another class, the class name will automatically appear in the results of the query.

Comment: A LOT LOT LOT THANKS, after my job, I'll try this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your query is working perfectly. I thought that putting everything in one table makes things simpler. Database normalisation is new thing for me, but I love to learn new things. THANKS AGAIN